# Write a function that return true if 2 passed strings to it are such that all characters of first string are uniquely present in second string

Tags: c

Efficient and O(n) code for this in c??
I know that solution of O(n*n)

```
stringCompare(str1, str2){
int freq1[100] = {0}, i;
int freq2[100]  = {0};

for(i=0; i<=strlen(str1); i++){
     freq1[str1[i]]+ = 1;
}

for(i=0; i<=strlen(str2); i++)

{
     freq2[str2[i]]+ = 1;
 }

for(i=0;i<26;i++){
     if(freq1[i]!=freq2[i])
      return 0;
   return 1;
```

}

```
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified `MAK`'s pseudocode slightly so it only uses one frequency count array. A positive value in the final freq array means a char in `s1` is not in `s2`. A negative value signals extra chars in `s2`.

```
function same(s1,s2):
    freq=array of zeros

    for i=0 to length of s1:
       freq[s1[i]]+=1

    for i=0 to length of s2:
       freq[s2[i]]-=1

    for i=0 to alphabet_size:
        if not freq[i]=0
            return "no"
    return "yes"
```

Comment: I am not coder but trying to write a code for this pseudo code: please help in cpmpleting  stringCompare(str1, str2){
int freq1[100] = {0}, i, j,k;
int freq2[100]  = {0};

for(i=0; i<=strlen(str1); i++) {
     freq1[str1[i]]+ = 1;
} for(j=0; j<=strlen(str2); j++)  { freq1[str1[j]]+ = 1; }

Answer (score 1):

Count the frequency of each character in the first string and also that in the second string. If both frequency counts are the same for all characters, we have a match.

I would post code, but this looks too much like homework. The explanation should be enough.

EDIT:

Pseudocode:

```
function same(s1,s2):
    freq1=array of zeros
    freq2=array of zeros

    for i=0 to length of s1:
       freq1[s1[i]]+=1

    for i=0 to length of s2:
       freq2[s2[i]]+=1

    for i=0 to alphabet_size:
        if not freq1[i]=freq2[i]:
            return "no"
    return "yes"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, its not a homework question but it is something I can gave solution in different ways but I want code for that which I can't make up..if you can thn plss do it.

Comment: @Akki: I've posted pseudocode. The logic should be clear from that.

Comment: @MAK: what is alphabet_size and could you help in understand  complexity of your solution.

Comment: @Akki: `alphabet_size` is the size of the alphabet. If all you are using are lowercase letters it can be 26. If all characters (i.e. all possible values of `char` type) are allowed, then it is 256. The complexity is O(n), where n is the length of the strings, assuming the alphabet size is fixed.

Comment: ok sounds gr8!! could you please check the code i posted in modified question..i am not coder so want to make sure that it is correct

Comment: @Akki: In your list, 'a' maps to 0 in the frequency array, 'b' maps to 1, 'c' maps to 2, and so on. But `freq[str[i]]++` increments the str[i]th index, which for 'a' is 65, b is 66 and so on. You should decrement the value so that say for 'a', the 0th element is incremented.

Comment: @MAK: result is not correct. for ex: if str1(abcc) and str2(abc) it will result true although it should not.

Comment: @Akki: I don't see how it returns true in that case. The count for 'c' is 2 for str1 and 1 for str2, which are not equal and should return "no" by my solution. Please debug your code (and read my earlier comment about it). As I said I am not going to post C code, please understand the logic and write/debug your own code - otherwise you will never learn. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of an O(n) solution, but O(nlogn) is obvious: sort the strings' characters, and compare results for equality

Comment: @Akki: I can HELP you with code, but I am not going to write code for you. Show me what you have already done and where you are stuck and I will help you

Comment: I am using quick sort (O(logn)) to sort that is fine now what you trying to say with compare results for equality?

Comment: you sort the characters within the string, right? Suppose the sorted strings are s1, and s2. All you have to do now is check if(strcmp(s1, s2) == 0). Bit the other answers provide the O(n) solution you were looking for, why are you going with mine?

Answer (score 0):

1. count occurrences for all characters in 2nd string (1 string lookup)
2. for each character in 1st string check if its count in 2nd string equals 1 (1 string lookup)

So you'll need to lookup each string once + memory buffer of the size of possible character values range.

That approach will check if each character from 1st string appears in 2nd exactly once. Changing it to check if each character appears in both strings equal number of times (if that's the problem) should be trivial.